# Swift ImageCropper returns an image outside of the specified "window"

Tags: swift, webview, uiimageview, crop, image-size

I am making an app that has a UIWebView along with a button on a single view controller. When the button is clicked, an image (of the UIWebView) is captured using UIGraphicsContext.

This part works great! But when the button is clicked, after capturing the image, it displays the image as a subview on the same view, and I have been trying to use an ImageCropper Library that draws a CGRect in another subview over the UIImageView on the screen with a submit button. The rectangle itself can be resized (dragging the corners/edges) and moved around the view.

When the submit button is clicked, another subview is displayed in the top left hand portion of screen and display the image that was cropped (after clicking submit button) The idea is to only capture what is inside the rectangle. I am able to get the code working but the image captured is of the same image but not a section that is inside the CGRect.

I have 3 images that show how it works and shows the image that is cropped incorrectly.enter image description here . [Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL1jy.png) . [Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjZCj.png)
[Shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31QlT.png). I believe my problems lies within the size of image captured and the size of the image with the crop rect are not equal and that is why it is distorting it.

Does anyone know what might be the cause? Sorry for the long winded question but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code below:

**ViewController.swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    imageView.isHidden = true
    let aString = URL(string: "https://www.kshuntfishcamp.com/home.page")
    webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: aString!))
    super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func takePhotoPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    if let aContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(){
        webView.layer.render(in: aContext)
    }

    let capturedImage:UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 123, width: 330, height: 330))
    let image = capturedImage
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.isHidden = true
    webView.isHidden = true

    let editView = EditImageView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let image2 = capturedImage!
    editView.initWithImage(image: image2)

    let croppedImage = editView.getCroppedImage()

    self.view.addSubview(editView)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

EditImageView.swift - source (https://github.com/Thanatos-L/LyEditImageView)-only including parts that seem relevant to solving the problem

```
func initWithImage(image:UIImage){
    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 123, width: 330, height: 330))
    imageView.tag = IMAGE_VIEW_TAG;
    self.addSubview(self.imageView)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
    let frame = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imageView.frame.size, insideRect: self.frame);
    imageView.frame = frame
    originImageViewFrame = frame
    NSLog("initWithImage %@", NSStringFromCGRect(originImageViewFrame))
    imageZoomScale = 1.0
    commitInit()
}

private func cropImage() {
    let rect = self.convert(cropView.frame, to: imageView)
    let imageSize = imageView.image?.size
    let ratio = originImageViewFrame.size.width / (imageSize?.width)!
    let zoomedRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x / ratio, y: rect.origin.y / ratio, width: rect.size.width / ratio, height: rect.size.height / ratio)
    let croppedImage = cropImage(image: imageView.image!, toRect: zoomedRect)

    var view: UIImageView? =  self.viewWithTag(1301) as? UIImageView
    if view == nil {
        view = UIImageView()
    }
    view?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: croppedImage.size.width , height: croppedImage.size.height)
    view?.image = croppedImage
    view?.tag = 1301
    self.addSubview(view!)
    }
```

Comment: Please could you edit your question to make it less like a wall of text. Also, it is best if you include some code to demonstrate what you are doing too. Make sure it is formatted using the <code> button. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I just added the code, had to leave while writing question and didn't have time to insert code until now.